# Given an Facebook access token, how can I determine which Graph API version generated it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has a debug tool to inspect an individual token and review which Graph API version was used to generate it. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Is there a corresponding API to determine the graph version of a token as well?

Comment: Can you please add more details as to what you are planning to do with this information? It doesn't look like there is a way to determine the API version, but you can see other token related information using [this endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug).

Comment: During this Graph 2.0 transition period I would like to know which user tokens have which permissions, and if the Graph API version was a factor in permission change.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way I know of to determine with which version of the Graph API an Access Token was created.

But there's an endpoint with which you can inspect the permissions give by a user:

```
/{user_id}/permissions
```

documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/permissions/ You have to call this with a User Access Token.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook added a new HTTP header for all api versions called "facebook-api-version" that returns a version string like 'v2.0' for all Graph API requests.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#debugging